# How to _explicitly_ instantiate a variadic template while calling it

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

How can I *explicitly* instantiate a variadic function while calling it ?
The following code doesn't work and the compiler says that it couldn't convert the first parameter to a `string &&`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename ... Args>
void variadic( Args &&... args );

int main()
{
    string str;
    variadic<string &&, string &&>( str, ref( str ) );
}

template<typename ... Args>
void variadic( Args &&... args )
{
    ((cout << (void*)&args << endl), ...);
}
```

I have some code where the function object itself is a templated parameter which is invoked with some variadic parameters so that it has to be specialized before. Of course I could use a lambda as this parameter but maybe there's a simpler way.

Comment: please include the complete error message verbatim in the question. When i try to compile the error is not about a missing overload: https://godbolt.org/z/hqs5xn3PM

Answer (score 3):

Let the compiler deduce the arguments, and print them:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename ... Args>
void variadic( Args &&... args );

int main()
{
    string str;
    variadic( str, ref( str ) );
}

template<typename ... Args>
void variadic( Args &&... args )
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << '\n';
    #else
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    #endif
    ((cout << (void*)&args << endl), ...);
}
```

This gives me:

```
void variadic(Args &&...) [Args = <std::basic_string<char> &, std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_string<char>>>]
```

Shorten `std::basic_string<char>` to `std::string`, and you get:

```
variadic<std::string &, std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>( str, ref( str ) );
```

Why do we see those?

Firstly, when you don't specify template arguments here, `args` acts as a *forwarding reference*. When receiving lvalues, those deduce the underlying template parameter to an lvalue reference, so `std::string &` instead of `std::string` (the latter would be used for an rvalue).

Secondly, `std::ref()` returns `std::reference_wrapper<...>`, so it's wrong to use `std::string` directly.

---

Also: this is not an "explicit instantiation" (that would be `template void variadic<...>(...);`). You're just specifying template arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Your explicit template arguments specification is **not** the issue here.

The problem is that **neither** `str`, **nor** `std::ref(str)` are `std::string` **R-values** (which is what `std::string &&` mentioned in the template instantiation is).

You need to use [**`std::move(str)`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to make `str` compatible with the function parameter of type `std::string &&`:

```
string str;
variadic<string&&>(std::move(str));
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: The arguments don't have to be rvalue references (and can't be, because expressions never have reference types). They just have to be rvalues of the right type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I didn't get your point. Feel free to edit my question if something is inaccurate (or please explain in a comment).

Comment: `void foo(std::string &&); foo(std::string("42"));` - this compiles, even though `std::string("42")` is not an rvalue reference. My point is that instead of *"The problem is that [...] are not rvalue references"*, you should say *"are not rvalues"*.

Comment: Now I got it. Of course you are right and what I actually had in mind originally. Anyway - fixed.